# Visual Studio 2017 - Test Runner - Debug Selected Tests - NUnit - Not Working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nunit, visual-studio-test-runner

When running `Debug Selected Tests` in Visual Studio 2017, debugger just starts briefly and shuts down with selected test turning blue icon with exclamation mark (inconclusive test).

Output window from `Debug` shows:

```
The program '[1852] testhost.x86.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[1852] testhost.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Similar happens when using `Run Selected Tests` command (naturally, without debugging session popping up).

Funnily, running `Test -> Run -> All Tests` or `Test -> Debug -> All Tests` works fine.

Unit tests in the project are written against `NUnit 3.x` framework.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add missing Nuget package `NUnit3TestAdapter` to the unit-test project. After that both options `Debug Selected Tests` and `Run Selected Tests` started working as expected.

```
Install-Package NUnit3TestAdapter
```